# 'Nvidia X Server Setting' tab missing (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10, configuration

I have installed Nvidia (Geforce 940MX) Graphics driver version 384.111 from Softwares & Updates > Additional Drivers.

When I open "Nvidia X Server settings" it shows empty.
I have tried

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

and reinstall drive manually still facing the same issue.
I have tried to switch drivers and reboot the computer.

[image]

also, I switched to "Ubuntu xOrg" and reinstall the driver but no luck showing the same result like below image.

[image]

About page show as system uses **Intel Graphic Card**

[image]

Comment: What does `sudo prime-select nvidia` show?

Comment: after the purge, do a `apt install gtkorphan`, run `gtkorphan` as root and click on all orphaned packages, then click ok and keep doing that until the list is empty. Reboot and do: `sudo updatedb && locate nvidia`, [edit] your question and provide the output to the last command.  also a `ppa-list` would be welcome.  Then drop me a message @Fabby

Comment: @doug it show "the nvidia profile already set".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. i solved by disabling `secure boot` in my BIOS settings. And then the option was available.

Comment: you mean to say UEFI it's already been disabled.